# Can i save lots of bitmaps to one bitmap? (2d)

Tags: android, canvas

I have a 2-d array with cordinates for a 2d-map display.
These are drawed to a canvas. 
Its very heavy to draw these everytime i want to change something on my canvas, 
so i was thinking if it is possible to instead of For-looping thru the 2d-array, if i could save the result of the first time i do it, and restore from the save everytime i change something else then the 2d-map.

seems as canvas.save() and canvas.restore() can only be called equally times, so i cant store the first output, and then restore it 123 times.

I was thinking if it was possible to save the canvas in some other way, maybe by saving the first result to a bipmap?

I know i cannot "tweak"/"edit" anything that allready is drawn to the canvas, 
the map never changes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok so i figured it out. 
I can draw my background containing lots of images to one bitmap using canvas, its pretty simpel.

First create an empty bitmap with desired int height and int width, this will be the bitmap tht you will draw all your tiles to (small images).

Bitmap background = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, heigth, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

(Not sure about the syntax Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444 , use tooltip)
Then create a canvas with new Canvas(bitmap), this will make the canvas write to the bitmap.

Canvas canvas new Canvas(background);

Now you can write the canvas as you please, all will be stored in the bitmap for later use.

Comment: It will not going to consume lot of memory?

Comment: @Arjun he tends to use an empty bitmap with size = w x h , all pixel ARGB = 00 00 00 00 first, then use canvas to draw sth in the bitmap, drawing process can be drawing few steps: draw text/lines/rect/path/bitmap/otherthing into the canvas. And finally the original 00 00 00 00 bitmap will be updated with final colors pixels. We only need to keep the final bitmap of size w x h.