# How can i use canvas.save and canvas.restore?

Tags: java, android, android-canvas

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Can i save lots of bitmaps to one bitmap? (2d)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962188/can-i-save-lots-of-bitmaps-to-one-bitmap-2d)

I wonder how canvas.save and canvas.restore really works.

how i want it to work, and how i use it (but doesnt work).

1. lock the canvas
2. do some drawing with out unlockandpost
3. canvas.save() (store the int)
4. Do some more drawings
5. Post the canvas
6. Restore the canvas from step 3
7. Do some more drawings, repeat from 6 (loop)

What i really need is to save my canvas at a certain stage ( the background), and then draw objects above it, without having to draw the background everytime i want to update my canvas.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Canvas.save() & restore() don't act on the bitmap attached to the canvas... they exist to control aspects of the canvas drawing environment, specifically the current clipping area and the matrix.

You'd use save() and restore if you wanted to, say, draw a rotated sprite. To do that, you'd first save() the current canvas state, then you'd translate() so that the origin - pixel address (0,0) - is where you want the sprite to go, then you'd rotate(), and then you can drawBitmap(). Finally you can restore() the drawing environment back to normal.

So you're basically doomed to draw the background every time. If this is a complex operation, store it in an offscreen bitmap. So long as the background can be drawn in a single operation (drawBitmap, say) performance shouldn't suffer too much.

Comment: Thank you. Is there anyway to create a bitmap from an array of bitmaps ? Or simulair

Comment: Nope. You shouldn't need that kind of shortcut anyway... its simple work to iterate a list of drawables and draw each one to a canvas.

Comment: Well, with a 2d-array, 20 rows with 50 cols, its very much drawing to be done every frame...

Comment: Right, so you draw all those things *once* to an offscreen bitmap!

Comment: Any workflow to follow there? Havent really worked so much with this stuff... any tutorial?

Comment: Just thinking about it, I guess the advantage here is that if you wanted one rotated object one way, and another rotated object some other way, you save the non-rotated canvas both times before a Canvas.rotate() followed by a Canvas.restore() on both operations.  If we didn't have this save() & restore() flow and was stuck with raw rotate() method, the current canvas state could not account for both rotated objects so the bitmap matrix on the canvas would have to be rotate directly.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so I figured it out. 
I can draw my background containing lots of images to one bitmap using canvas, its pretty simple.

First create an empty bitmap with desired int height and int width, this will be the bitmap that you will draw all your tiles too (small images).

Bitmap background = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, heigth, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444);

(Not sure about the syntax Bitmap.Config.ARGB_4444 , use tooltip)
Then create a canvas with new Canvas(bitmap), this will make the canvas write to the bitmap.

Canvas canvas new Canvas(background);

Now you can write the canvas as you please, all will be stored in the bitmap for later use.